# Finding limit $ \lim_{{x\rightarrow0},y\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos xy-2^{x{y}^2}}{x^2y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Compute or show that a limit
$$L: \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos xy-2^{x{y}^2}}{x^2y^2}$$
doesn't exist. Here is my approach:

First I divided the limit into two limits first one is

$\lim_{{x\rightarrow0},y\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos xy}{x^2y^2}$ (Lets call this limit $L_1$)

And second is $\lim_{{x\rightarrow0},y\rightarrow0}\frac{2^{x{y}^2}}{x^2y^2}$. (And call this $L_2$)

When solving $L_1$ I substituted $xy=t, t\rightarrow 0$ and I get

$\lim_{{t\rightarrow0}}\frac{\cos t}{t^2}$, Since this is $\frac{constant}{0}$ this is undefined end hence the limit does not exist, which indicates that also limit $L$ does not exist?

Is this okay, if not what other approach can be made?

Comment: Why is it that the argument that you used to prove that the limit $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos t}t$ doesn't exist doesn't apply to the limit $L_1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh I see, I complicated unnecessarily :D So does that mean that the limit L does not exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a tip on how to solve it maybe?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the limits$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}\tag1$$and$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2^{xy^2}-1}{x^2y^2}.\tag2$$Since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}=-\frac12$, the limit $(1)$ is equal to $\frac12$. However, the limit $(2)$ doesn't exist, since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{2^t-1}t=\log2$, and therefore$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2^{xy^2}-1}{xy^2}=\log(2),$$from which it follows that indeed the limit $(2)$ does not exist. But then, since$$\frac{\cos(xy)-2^{xy^2}}{x^2y^2}=\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}-\frac{2^{xy^2}-1}{x^2y^2},$$your limit also doesn't exist.

Comment: I just don't understand when solving limit $(2)$ in the denominator is $x^2y^2$ so it couldn't have been replaced with t?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}=-\frac12$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|t|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}+\frac12\right|=0$. But then, if $\|(x,y)\|<\sqrt[4]\delta$, you have $|x|,|y|<\sqrt[4]\delta$, and therefore $x^2y^2<\delta$. It follows from this that$$\left|\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}+\frac12\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

To see explicitely that the limit doesn't exist let consider $x=y= t \to 0$

$$\frac{\cos xy-2^{x{y}^2}}{x^2y^2}=\frac{\cos t^2-2^{t^3}}{t^4}=\frac{\cos t^2-1}{t^4}-\frac1{t}\frac{2^{t^3}-1}{t^3}\to -\frac12\pm\infty\cdot\log 2=\pm\infty$$